# Put Assembly Version from AssemblyInfo.cs in Web.config

Tags: .net, powershell, web-config

I have this scenario, where I have the project's Assembly Version from AssemblyInfo.cs, for example 2.0.0 as below:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0")]
```

In addition, I would like to retrieve this AssemblyVersion and set it as part of the parameters in my web.config dynamically, such as below, for example:

```
<my.config.group>
    <version versionNumber="2.0.0" />
</my.config.group>
```

I need to set the version number above, as the version number of my Assembly dynamically, to avoid having to modify it manually when something changes.

This is required because of how a third party library we are using works. Therefore, it is not possible to fetch the assembly version using an alternative way. We must stick to the web.config.

What is the neatest solution to achieve this? I was thinking of using a Powershell script Post-Build, however, I have little experience in Powershell so I wanted to know what is the best solution.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why does (some piece of code) need, specifically, to read this from web.config when it could (presumably) just access the assembly version information directly?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the web.config parameter mention is used by a third party library, so that's out of my control, what I need to do from my end is find a way to get the assembly version and add it within the versionNumber="" parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could do that using a post build event, but you can also do it as a deployment step or whatsoever.

The following script loads the assembly, reads the version information and formats a string. Then, it creates the version node on the config file if not present and sets the versionNumber attribute:

```
$assemblyFilePath = "C:\YourAssembly.dll"
$configPath = "C:\YourWeb.config"

# Retrieve the version
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($assemblyFilePath)
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)
$version = $assembly.GetName().Version;
$versionString = [string]::Format("{0}.{1}.{2}",$version.Major, $version.Minor, $version.Build)

$config = [xml](gc $configPath)
$versionNode = $config.SelectSingleNode('configuration//version')
# Ensure the version node is present
if (-not $versionNode)
{
    $versionNode = $config.CreateElement('version')
    $config.DocumentElement.AppendChild($versionNode)
}
# Set the version number attribute
$versionNode.SetAttribute('versionNumber', $versionString)
$config.Save($configPath)
```

You could also read and parse the `AssemblyVersion` attribute from the `AssemblyInfo.cs`. The reason why I prefer to load the assembly itselfs is because you can use this solution even if you only have the binaries.

And here an example how you can read the version from the `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
$assemblyInfoPath = "C:\AssemblyInfo.cs"

$regex = '^\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*?)"\)\]'
$assemblyInfo = Get-Content $assemblyInfoPath -Raw

$version = [Regex]::Match(
        $assemblyInfo, 
        $regex,
        [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline
    ).Groups[1].Value
```

Now you can parse the version using `[version]::Parse($version)`and use the same format string as the example above.

Comment: this looks exactly like what I am after, the only change I will make is that I will load it from the AssemblyInfo, since that would always be available in my case

Comment: I added an exmaple how you can read the version from the AssemblyInfo.cs