# I need first 3 digit number of version from AssemblyInfo.cs using powershell script

Tags: string, powershell, variables, .net-assembly

In our project, We have AssemblyInfo.cs

Here is some code...

```
 [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.5.26.0")]
 [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.5.26.0")]
```

**What I want is the first three-digits numbers of the version.**

I have one Powershell script, which gets the version but I need only first three digits

```
$assemblyInfoPath = "D:\PC- Downloads\AssemblyInfo.cs"

$regex = '^\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*?)"\)\]'
$assemblyInfo = Get-Content $assemblyInfoPath -Raw

  $version = [Regex]::Match(
    $assemblyInfo, 
    $regex,
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline
).Groups[1].Value
```

reference link: [Put Assembly Version from AssemblyInfo.cs in Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938239/put-assembly-version-from-assemblyinfo-cs-in-web-config)

Is anyone have an idea of how I can achieve?

Comment: You could cast the version numbers to real version numbers `[VERSION]"1.5.26.0"`. Now you can call `Major`, `Minor` and `Build`. ;-)

Comment: could you please give some examples with PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm ... I'll try ... assumed you have the source string saved to variable `$sourceString`:

```
$sourceString = '[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.5.26.0")]'
```

You can cut of everything you don't need and cast the result to a proper dot Net Version type:

```
[VERSION]$VersionString = $sourceString -replace '^.+((\d+\.){3}\d+).+', '$1'
```

Now you can access all single elements by their name:

```
$VersionString.Major
$VersionString.Minor
$VersionString.Build
$VersionString.Revision

$VersionString
```

Result would be this:

```
1
5
26
0

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
---- - ---- - ---- - --------
1      5      26     0
```

Now you can re-join them  as you need them

```
$DhartisNeed = '{0}.{1}.{2}' -f $VersionString.Major,$VersionString.Minor,$VersionString.Build
$DhartisNeed
```

Result would be this:

```
1.5.26
```

Comment: I got the same result in my script, what I need is I need only three-digit no last "0" and output should be like this: "1.5.26"

Also dont want to put $sourceString = '[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.5.26.0")]' as hard coded , Version should fatch automatic from  AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Comment: I thought that would have been obvious. You can re-join the single parts as needed ...  I added one example for you.  ;-)   My variable names are just examples. You are allowed to change everything to your special needs.

Comment: I have version "**1.06.04**" but when I use the above script for getting a version it is showing "**1.6.4**". Is there any idea?

Comment: AFAIK leading zeros are just eye candy. They do not matter actually from a technical point of view. Why do you think you need them? If you really need them you would need to create a string with the special *design*. ;-)  ... and why is it not "**01.06.04**"?

Comment: It is a matter for me! if you have any idea just let me know

Comment: ... an idea for what? If you need a format different from the standard you will have to build it by yourself.